# Dart: debugging dart app doesn't work from within WebStorm, running works fine

Tags: dart, webstorm

I am using webstorm. And I have setup a small sample app. Running the app displays the following in the output window

```
C:/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe --ignore-unrecognized-flags C:/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/TestDart/TestMe.dart
You are using Windows

Process finished with exit code 0
```

but when debugging it just sits there with the following output

```
C:/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe --ignore-unrecognized-flags --debug:57939 C:/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/TestDart/TestMe.dart
```

I have a breakpoint set in the main() funciton on this line, but it never hits it

```
  stdout.write("You are using ");
```

I have no firewall and also I don't think i need dartium installed as this is just a standard console application that prints things out.

Anyone have any success?

thanks

Comment: What i have found is if I remove the break point then it outputs just like when I run it. But having a breakpoint, its never hit and just seems to hang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging Dart console application doesn't currently work:( Please watch [WEB-9937](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9937) to be notified on any progress

Comment: Great, thanks for the that, I starred it and i will keep my eye on it. Thanks again